# Conversion is not happening in Nreco for Chinese currency

Tags: c#, wkhtmltopdf, pdf-conversion, nreco

I am using NRECo to convert HTML string to Bytes for pdf conversion. Everything works fine but in a string, When I insert Chinese currency symbol (¥) but after conversion, I am seeing  Â¥. How do I need to solve this issue?

```
CNY(¥) Cost
```

converts to

```
CNY(Â¥) Cost
```

Below code which I am using for conversion.

```
var converter = new NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter();
   var pdfBytes = converter.GeneratePdf(html);
   return pdfBytes;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that you've specified UTF-8 encoding in your HTML template with meta-tag:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
```